# "Failed to start apply kernel variables" on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, katoolin

After installing katoolin on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and rebooting my laptop, I got this message:

[image]

[image]

What should I do to get back my Ubuntu?